Force bonding withdrawal period to 0 days
I run a local testnode using chopsticks and I want to unbond funds right after I bond them.
What configuration I could use in chopsticks or RPC call I could make to make sure I can withdraw my funds as soon as I want.

Check out the BondingDuration parameter - this number represents the number of eras that funds need to be bonded for.
Alternatively, another pallet you can configure in your runtime is pallet-fast-unstake, that'll allow stakers to immediately unbond until they become exposed (actively backing a validator) for an era.

Thanks for your answer! I might have not precise it in the post but I use polkadotjs so I'm not sure how I can configure the bondingDuration from there

Changing the BondingDuration is not something you can do on the UI side - it is a runtime constant, so it needs to be configured in your runtime config and then deployed with a runtime upgrade. If you are just running a dev node then upgrades are not needed - just change the runtime configuration and re-build.

Thanks a lot! So I need to clone polkadot-sdk, change the constant, rebuild it and run chopsticks with --wasm-runtime-overrides that's correct ?

Overriding the storage is plausible option here ?
